# Cross-compile Apache apr-util library for ARM - Linux platform

Tags: apache, arm, embedded-linux

first post~

I'm trying to port ActiveMQ-cpp client to an ARM platform (Beaglebone/BeagleBoard) - since I'm doing my development on my PC, I'll need to cross-compile the ActiveMQ-cpp library in order for it to run on the ARM systems.

I follow through the steps in their [building instruction](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/building.html), except I compile the APR and the APR-util library using the following:

For APR:

./configure --prefix=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/apr --host=arm-linux-gnueabi CC="arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc" CXX="arm-linux-gnueabi-g++"
I run make install and things are fine.

For APR-util:

./configure --prefix=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/apr-util --host=arm-linux-gnueabi -with-apr=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/apr CC="arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc" CXX="arm-linux-gnueabi-g++"
I run make install and got this:

```
/home/peter/apache/Apache_apr/apr-util-1.5.1/xml/expat/.libs/libexpat.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
```

After some search, I 'think' the issue is with libexpat being the in the wrong format (compiled for i386?)

My question is: How to I properly compile ActiveMQ-cpp library for a ARM-platform? Is there some way I can fix the libexpat.so? or skip Apr-util? or some option in the ./configure for Apr-util?

Follow-up:
Here is the log file from running configure:

```
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
checking target system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for working mkdir -p... yes
APR-util Version: 1.5.1
checking for chosen layout... apr-util
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc... arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
Applying apr-util hints file rules for arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
checking for APR... yes
  setting CPP to "gcc -E"
  adding "-pthread" to CFLAGS
  setting CPPFLAGS to " -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE"
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for ldap support...
checking for default DBM... sdbm (default)
checking for pg_config... no
checking libpq-fe.h usability... no
checking libpq-fe.h presence... no
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
checking postgresql/libpq-fe.h usability... no
checking postgresql/libpq-fe.h presence... no
checking for postgresql/libpq-fe.h... no
checking sqlite3.h usability... no
checking sqlite3.h presence... no
checking for sqlite3.h... no
checking sqlite.h usability... no
checking sqlite.h presence... no
checking for sqlite.h... no
checking sybdb.h usability... no
checking sybdb.h presence... no
checking for sybdb.h... no
checking freetds/sybdb.h usability... no
checking freetds/sybdb.h presence... no
checking for freetds/sybdb.h... no
checking for odbc_config... no
checking sql.h usability... no
checking sql.h presence... no
checking for sql.h... no
checking odbc/sql.h usability... no
checking odbc/sql.h presence... no
checking for odbc/sql.h... no
checking Expat 1.95.x... no
checking old Debian-packaged expat... no
checking old FreeBSD-packaged expat... no
checking Expat 1.0/1.1... no
  setting LDFLAGS to "-L/usr/local/lib"
  adding "-I/usr/local/include" to CPPFLAGS
checking Expat 1.95.x in /usr/local... no
  nulling LDFLAGS
  removed "-I/usr/local/include" from CPPFLAGS
configuring package in xml/expat now
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
checking target system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc... arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc... /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-dlltool... dlltool
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-ar... arm-linux-gnueabi-ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-strip... arm-linux-gnueabi-strip
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-ranlib... arm-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-nm -B output from arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-mt... no
checking for mt... mt
configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc linker (/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc... (cached) arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for bcopy... yes
checking check.h usability... no
checking check.h presence... no
checking for check.h... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating expat_config.h
config.status: expat_config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing libtool commands
xml/expat configured properly
  setting APRUTIL_INCLUDES to "-I/home/jacky/apache/Apache_apr/apr-util-1.5.1/xml/expat/lib"
  setting LDFLAGS to "-L/home/jacky/apache/Apache_apr/apr-util-1.5.1/xml/expat/lib"
  setting APRUTIL_EXPORT_LIBS to "/home/jacky/apache/Apache_apr/apr-util-1.5.1/xml/expat/libexpat.la"
  setting APRUTIL_LIBS to "/home/jacky/apache/Apache_apr/apr-util-1.5.1/xml/expat/libexpat.la"
checking iconv.h usability... yes
checking iconv.h presence... yes
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for type of inbuf parameter to iconv... char **
checking for iconv.h... (cached) yes
checking langinfo.h usability... yes
checking langinfo.h presence... yes
checking for langinfo.h... yes
checking for nl_langinfo... yes
checking for CODESET in langinfo.h... yes
checking whether APR has DSO support... yes
checking for library containing crypt... -lcrypt
checking if system crypt() function is threadsafe... no
checking for crypt_r... yes
checking style of crypt_r... struct_crypt_data
  adding "/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/apr/lib/libapr-1.la" to APRUTIL_LIBS
  adding "-luuid" to APRUTIL_LIBS
  adding "-lrt" to APRUTIL_LIBS
  adding "-lcrypt" to APRUTIL_LIBS
  adding "-lpthread" to APRUTIL_LIBS
  adding "-ldl" to APRUTIL_LIBS
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating export_vars.sh
config.status: creating build/pkg/pkginfo
config.status: creating apr-util.pc
config.status: creating apu-1-config
config.status: creating include/private/apu_select_dbm.h
config.status: creating include/apr_ldap.h
config.status: creating include/apu.h
config.status: creating include/apu_want.h
config.status: creating test/Makefile
config.status: creating include/private/apu_config.h
config.status: executing default commands
```

From what I can see, xml/expat configured properly. I thought - maybe I need to compile expat library in gcc-arm-linux? I went on, do that, and run the configure again:

./configure --prefix=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/apr-util --host=arm-linux-gnueabi -with-apr=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/apr -with-expat=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/expat CC="arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc" CXX="arm-linux-gnueabi-g++"

I got similar result in the log, except I now have Expat 1.95.x:

```
checking for odbc/sql.h... no
  setting LDFLAGS to "-L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/expat/lib"
  adding "-I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/expat/include" to CPPFLAGS
  setting APRUTIL_INCLUDES to "-I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/expat/include"
  setting APRUTIL_LDFLAGS to "-L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/expat/lib"
checking Expat 1.95.x... yes
  setting APRUTIL_EXPORT_LIBS to "-lexpat"
  setting APRUTIL_LIBS to "-lexpat"
```

run make, same error occurred.

I did a search on errors related to libexpat.so. I notice those who wants to cross-compile usually see this "libexpat.so" error: with [centos 5.2 64bits](http://www.directadmin.com/forum/showthread.php?t=27045&page=1), with or another case with Xeon 64bit.

Below is the command that actually cause the error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jacky/apache/Apache_apr/apr-util-1.5.1'
/bin/bash /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/apr/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=link  gcc -g -O2 -pthread   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE   -I/home/jacky/apache/Apache_apr/apr-util-1.5.1/include -I/home/jacky/apache/Apache_apr/apr-util-1.5.1/include/private  -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/apr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/expat/include  -version-info 5:1:5    -o libaprutil-1.la -rpath /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/apr-util/lib buckets/apr_brigade.lo buckets/apr_buckets.lo buckets/apr_buckets_alloc.lo buckets/apr_buckets_eos.lo buckets/apr_buckets_file.lo buckets/apr_buckets_flush.lo buckets/apr_buckets_heap.lo buckets/apr_buckets_mmap.lo buckets/apr_buckets_pipe.lo buckets/apr_buckets_pool.lo buckets/apr_buckets_refcount.lo buckets/apr_buckets_simple.lo buckets/apr_buckets_socket.lo crypto/apr_crypto.lo crypto/apr_md4.lo crypto/apr_md5.lo crypto/apr_passwd.lo crypto/apr_sha1.lo crypto/crypt_blowfish.lo crypto/getuuid.lo crypto/uuid.lo dbd/apr_dbd.lo dbm/apr_dbm.lo dbm/apr_dbm_sdbm.lo dbm/sdbm/sdbm.lo dbm/sdbm/sdbm_hash.lo dbm/sdbm/sdbm_lock.lo dbm/sdbm/sdbm_pair.lo encoding/apr_base64.lo hooks/apr_hooks.lo ldap/apr_ldap_stub.lo ldap/apr_ldap_url.lo memcache/apr_memcache.lo misc/apr_date.lo misc/apr_queue.lo misc/apr_reslist.lo misc/apr_rmm.lo misc/apr_thread_pool.lo misc/apu_dso.lo misc/apu_version.lo strmatch/apr_strmatch.lo uri/apr_uri.lo xlate/xlate.lo xml/apr_xml.lo    -luuid -lrt -lcrypt  -lpthread -ldl -L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/expat/lib -lexpat /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/apr/lib/libapr-1.la -luuid -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/expat/lib/libexpat.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libaprutil-1.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jacky/apache/Apache_apr/apr-util-1.5.1'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Many thanks to your help!

Comment: You should probably save & examine the log file output by the `configure` program.  BTW for building various packages I like to specify the cross-compile using something like `$ ./configure --target=arm-linux --host=arm-linux --build=i386-pc-linux-gnu ...`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some library build earlier in different format. Due to which you are getting the error: 
File in wrong format
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Run file command over /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/expat/lib/libexpat.so
If it shows for some different format then you need to rebuild it.
But its weird as I think its an pre-build arm library and it should be in correct format.